# How to add scrollbars in PyQt4 WITHOUT with absolute positioning

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm creating an interface in PyQt4, and I am in need of scrollbars. My interface uses absolute positioning. I have looked a other treads for adding scrollbars, but the only answers given are to those interfaces without a layout (such as VBoxLayout, Grid Layout, etc).

Please take a look at my code. How could I add a scrollbars (horizontal and vertical) to this interface?

The full code wouldn't format properly on here, so I'll link to this pastebin

http://pastebin.com/hEH4R534

Here is the base of the interface (a 1500px by 1000px window)

```
    class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self):

            super(Example, self).__init__()
            self.initUI()


       def initUI(self):
            self.setGeometry(100,100,1500,1000)




  def main():
     import sys
     app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
     window = Example()
     window.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())

  main()
```

The question is... How would I modify the code above so I have horizontal and vertical scrollbars?

Answer (score 0):

Only widgets that inherit from [QAbstractScrollArea](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractscrollarea.html) can have scroll bars.  You could place one of those widgets inside your widget, and then place other widgets inside that widget.  Or, just have your widget inherit from QScrollArea instead of QWidget.

By default, scroll bars will only appear when necessary to display hidden child widgets.  You can force scroll bars to appear by setting the scroll bar policy for the widget.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

...

def initUI(self):
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1500, 1000)
    self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
```

Comment: This got me one step closer, but when I change the inheritance (by replacing QtGui.QWidget with QtGui.QScrollArea) and try to resize the window, no scrollbars appeared.